# Convert column of lists to lists of binary matrix

Tags: python, list, binary, sequential

I want to convert the following list of lists:

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [1],
 [3,2]]
```

To such form of binary matrix:

```
[[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]],
[[1,0,0]],
[[0,0,1],[0,1,0]]]
```

I have tried with keras 'to_categorical' funtion, which requires an array as input. However in my case the lists of sequences are of irregular length. I have tried padding the lists so the function works, but then I got stuck on the problem of unpadding.

Comment: You can apply `to_categorical` to each input in your list, for example something like that:
`for d in data: binary_masks.append(tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(d, num_classes=num_classes))
`

Comment: @coder00 Easy as that! Thanks! For some reason I thought to_categorical wouldn't work in a loop... For anyone else with similar case - you just need to convert the output (list of arrays) using .tolist(): [l.tolist() for l in binary_masks]

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the number of items in each sublist will be the given by the highest integer over each sublist, i.e., 3 in this case. you can transform the int sublists in binary doing:

```
mylist = [[1, 2, 3],
 [1],
 [3,2]]

maxN = max([max(i) for i in mylist]) # Get the overall max integer
newlist = []
for l in mylist:
    sublist = []
    for i in l:
        newitem = [0]*maxN # Create an array of zeros
        newitem[i-1] = 1 # Insert 1 just in the position given by the int
        sublist.append(newitem) # Builds sublist
    newlist.append(sublist) # Builds main list
newlist
```

Output:

```
[[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [[1, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursion to go through the list nesting and output a list of bits at the bottom level (for items that are not lists):

```
def toBin(A,bits=3):
    if isinstance(A,list):
        return [toBin(a,bits) for a in A]
    return list(map(int,f"{A:0{bits}b}"))
```

output:

```
A = [[1, 2, 3],
 [1],
 [3,2]]

print(toBin(A))
[[[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]], 
 [[0, 0, 1]], 
 [[0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0]]]
```